# JLayeredPane error when the layer is an Integer

Tags: java, swing, autoboxing, jlayeredpane

I have a Canvas subclass object that I'm trying to add, along with some other Canvas subclasses, to a JLayeredPane.  In the documentation for JLayeredPane, the layer is given as an Integer, e.g.

```
layeredPane.add(child, new Integer(0));
```

However, when I use an Integer for the layer, I get some kind of runtime error.  (I can't really tell what this error is because my IDE keeps complaining about the lack source for the Swing libraries.)  Oddly, when I use the following form:

```
layeredPane.add(child, 0);
```

the line actually executes error-free.  I'm very new to Java and still haven't figured out how autoboxing works other than to form the opinion that it doesn't work very well.  I'm not sure if the bare 0 would be autoboxed in this case.

I wish I could add more detail about this error, but I'm not even seeing an exception.  I will work on trimming my code down to a simple example, but I was hoping someone with experience with JLayeredPane has seen this before.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see what you are doing

Comment: See [`Container.add(Component,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29).  That is where the method originates from, and it does not claim to accept an `Integer`, but an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't add comment so I will leave reply.
If you work with IDE then you can use design form to create your GUI easily, just drag-&-drop thing....

I have worked with JLayeredPane and if you add component to it you can use add method manually like `layeredPane.add(Component, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);` or `layeredPane.add(Component, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);`

Use static constant Integer field and read the JLayeredPane API, or some examples of using it on oracle. Its a good feature to learn.

Comment: I had tried using JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER before posting, but both JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER and JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER produce the same unidentifiable error.  I think it's probably best if I boil this down to a few-line example so I can post the entire problematic source.

Comment: This error had something to do with the fact that I was using BorderLayout on the JLayeredPane.  The error went away when I changed to another layout.

Comment: Good that you itself figured out, because all other trouble shooting was not helpful. The layout manager is a tricky thing when working with Swing!!

Answer (score 0):

This error had something to do with the fact that I was using BorderLayout on the JLayeredPane. The error went away when I changed to another layout.